# Checkbox inside a gridview change after page load in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a radiobutton list named rdbModules and a `GridView` named `dgvMenu.dgvMenu` contains five `CheckBox`es name `chkSelect`,`chkAdd`,`chkUpdate`,`chkDelete`,`chkReport`.

I have populated `dgvMenu` from the database depends on the selection of `rdbModule`.

The problem in when I am selecting checkbox inside the gridview it is working fine.

Suppose I have selected first item from `radiobuttonlist` and then selected some `checkboxes` from `gridview`. After that if I select the second or any other other options from the radio button list i am not able to get the selected checkbox details inside the gridview  for the selection of first item of the radio button list.

Comment: You want to get the selected checkboxes from dgvMenu when rdbModules selection change?

Comment: yes....but some how it is getting changed when rdbModules selection is changed

Comment: How do you fill the gridview?

Comment: foreach (ListItem item in rdbModules .Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        string selectedValue = item.Value;
                        dt = objSec.ShowSubMenuModuleWise(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
                        dgvMenu.DataSource = dt;
                        dgvMenu.DataBind();
                    }
                }

Comment: Do you use this code in an event or Page_Load?

Comment: in Page_Load i have written this...

If(!IsPostBack)
{
   //another function which is binding the gridview for Admin Users
}

Comment: Which event? Update your answer and post the code

Comment: rdbModules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rdbModules .Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected))
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in rdbModules.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        string selectedValue = item.Value;
                        dt = objSec.ShowSubMenuModuleWise(selectedValue);
                        dgvMenu.DataSource = dt;
                        dgvMenu.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: With this event you update the gridview when the selection change... Just iterate through your gridview and get selected checkboxes before updating it

Comment: Can u please provide me the code.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
rdbModules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //Loop through your gridview here
    foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvMenu.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkboxid")).Checked)
        {
             //do what you want            
        }            
    }

    if (rdbModules .Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected)) 
    { 
        foreach (ListItem item in rdbModules.Items) 
        { 
            if (item.Selected) 
            { 
                string selectedValue = item.Value; 
                dt = objSec.ShowSubMenuModuleWise(selectedValue); 
                dgvMenu.DataSource = dt; dgvMenu.DataBind(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think I am not able to explain my situation.

Comment: There is no issue in checkbox selection inside the gridview.But whenever I am changing the rdbModule_SelectedIndexChanged the previous record of the gridview is not coming.
Should I use viewsate for this.If yes then how

Comment: What do you mean by "coming"?

Comment: Whatever I have selected in the gridview checkbox for the first Item of RadioButtonList is getting unchecked after re selection of that item in Radiobuttonlist. It will be better if I show u the screenshot.But since I dnt have that much reputation for attaching the screen shot

Comment: If you want the changes to be saved you have to update your database. Thus you will load the updated data when re selecting an item. You could also use viewstate but you will need one for each option of the RadioButtonList.